# Basic auth in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, basic-authentication

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index]
  before_action :authenticate, :except => [:index]

  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      basic_auth=User.find_by_email(username)
      if basic_auth.valid_password?(password)
        sign_in :user, basic_auth
        render :json => {:email => current_user.email, :id => current_user.id, :message => "hai ruby"}
      else
        render plain: "Unauthorized access"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I am trying to implement basic authorization in my sample application.When i give correct credentials values as in the user database. It gives json response.when the username and password goes wrong it throws error as "undefined method `valid_password?' for nil:NilClass"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change if condition to this:

`if basic_auth && basic_auth.valid_password?(password)`

This will work because before checking for valid password, you must check whether a user even exists with given email id or not. Otherwise, basic_auth object will be nil and valid_password method on nil object will throw error.